# Python: instance attribute is deleted after shuffling

Tags: python, class, attributes, overloading

I have a trouble with a strange behaviour of numpy.random.shuffle function.
I add attribute to instances but it is erased after shuffling.

Here is a code illustrating the problem:

```
#I'm making a class of time series.
class TimeSeries(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.num_points = len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.data[key]

    def __len__(self):
        return self.num_points

dataset = [TimeSeries(numpy.random.random((10,3))) for _ in range(100)]
#Add new attribute
for ts in dataset:
    ts.weight = 1

dataset[0].weight  #returns 1
numpy.random.shuffle(dataset)
dataset[0].weight  #'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'weight'
```

I want to keep the weight attribute, but deleted after the shuffle.
I have done some trials.
What I have foud are:

- If the data set is small, the problem does not happen. (e.g range(100) >> range(3))
- ids are change after the shuffle.
- If getitem, len methods are not implemented, the problem does not happens.

What's going on in the shuffle function? 
Is this a bug? Am I using the function is a wrong way?

Comment: Do you want to shuffle the list of timeseries, or do some kind of shuffling within each time series

Comment: I want to shuffle the list of timeseries. Thanks.

Comment: The fact that item zero has changed from a TimeSeries object to a numpy.ndarry object hints that the shuffle command is making some assumptions about the input.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to shuffle the main list, you could use

```
import random
random.shuffle(dataset)
```

Comment: random.shuffle works as I desired! But why I can not use numpy.random.shuffle?